# How to get `gradlew idea` to get IDEA to use test conf for custom task?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have the following:

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java.srcDir file('.')
    }
}

dependencies {
    integrationTestCompile project(':sut-project')
}

task integrationTest(type: Test)
```

but when `gradlew idea` is run and the project opened, the `Sources` doesn't have a `Tests` conf for that project.

What needs to be done to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for IDEA plugin is at http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html

From this links you can navigate to http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html where you can see how to map additional source roots (AKA content-roots in IntelliJ parlance) to your modules and configurations to classpath using proper scope. You will use something like:

`idea {
  module {
    testSourceDirs += file('src/integTest/java')
    scopes.TEST.plus += configurations.integrationTestCompile
  }
}`